# Nodejs reading and writing to the same file at the same time

Tags: node.js, express, file, filesystems, fs

I have a node.js application with express which write html files, and sometimes update them.
Is it a bad practice or breaking practice to write and read from the same file at the same time?

```
fs.writeFile(file_location,data)
res.sendFile(file_location)
```

The goal is to send the previously generated file before it updates.

Is it a bad practice to write the html data twice at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your purpose. But, I would not prefer this approach.
`res.sendFile` closes the connection and not the execution of the program and so the line next to it works.

```
res.sendFile(file_location)
fs.writeFileSync(file_location,data)
```

Comment: Why don't you recommend it?  Will the user only get the old file? Or can he get parts of the new file?